# How to send bigger push notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification

I just received a push notification from Slotomania that was much bigger than others. It also had a custom background color.

Anyone knows how to use these big push notifications?

[image]

Comment: what are you tried before?

Comment: this is not a 'make a project for me' site. Show your code implementation and ask about any error.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ***big push notifications***

private void sendNotification(String path, String fileName) {
    Context context = getBaseContext();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, yourActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(Constant.PATH_INTENT_KEY, path);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(Constant.FILENAME_INTENT_KEY, fileName);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0  /*Request code */, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigImage = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = null;
    int notificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();



    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setContentTitle(tittle)
            .setContentText(fileName)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR);

    File imgFile = new File(path);
    if (imgFile.exists()) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        notificationBuilder.setStyle(bigImage.bigPicture(bitmap));
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```